# Replace Contents of Request Object in Slim Middleware

Tags: slim, slim-3

I'm encrypting a header value and params of the request object. In the middleware.. I decrypt the values and would I like replace the values.

Tried the below. Doesnt seem to be working.
new \Slim\Http\Request($method, $uri, $headers, $cookies, $serverParams, $body)

```
For -  $response = $next($request, $response); I tried the below

$response = $next(new \Slim\Http\Request($request->getMethod(),$request->getUri(), $arr, $request->getCookieParams(), $request->getServerParams(), $request->getBody()), $response);
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to replace the header value:

```php
$value = $response->getHeaderLine('MyHeader');

// ...

$response = $response->withHeader('MyHeader', $value);
```